# How to get status of sqlite query?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

For example i have some sql query:

```sql
INSERT INTO categories(category, sub_category) 
    SELECT category, sub_category 
    FROM (SELECT "category" as category, "Final" as sub_category) temp 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM categories WHERE categories.category = temp.category AND categories.sub_category = temp.sub_category)
```

I execute it like this:

```py
async with aiosqlite.connect('categories.db') as db:
    await db.execute(sql)
    await db.commit()
```

But i have nothing in output. 
Can i somehow get status of this execute like `insertion complete` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a [Cursor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects) for the query and check how many things were inserted with [`rowcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount).

```py
async with aiosqlite.connect("test.db") as db:
    async with db.execute("insert into test values (1), (2)") as cursor:
        print("Total changes: {}".format(cursor.rowcount))
```

Comment: It doesnt work because ```print("insertion complete")``` printed all time because the ```await db.execute(sql)``` is always executed, but it can be done with different results and i need to get this result.

Comment: @kshnkvn Edited to demonstrate checking the rowcount of the last statement.